# Telerik radChart xaxis datacolumn not showing

Tags: c#, asp.net, charts, telerik, datacolumn

I have a datatable that I add to the chart in foreach loop as follow and assigning dtMonth datarow to xaxis of chart, which is month names:

```
                foreach (DataRow dr in dtMD.Rows)
                {

                    DataTable dtMDByName = ocw.GetMDByName(Convert.ToDateTime(txtStartDate.Text), Convert.ToDateTime(txtEndDate.Text), dr["MD"].ToString());

                    if (dtMDByName.Rows.Count > 0)
                    {
                        ChartSeries MDChartSeries = new ChartSeries();
                        MDChartSeries.Name = dtMDByName.Rows[0][1].ToString();
                        MDChartSeries.Type = ChartSeriesType.Line;

                        foreach (DataRow drByName in dtMDByName.Rows)
                        {
                            MDChartSeries.AddItem(Convert.ToDouble(drByName["T"]));

                            radMD.PlotArea.XAxis.DataLabelsColumn = drByName["dtMonth"].ToString();
                        }

                        radMD.ChartTitle.TextBlock.Text = "MDs";
                        radMD.PlotArea.XAxis.AutoScale = true;
                        radMD.Series.Add(MDChartSeries);

                    }
                }
```

but still it shows as numbers in xaxis, anything im doing wrong in above code?

even if I do it outside the second loop i.e following code still it doesn't show month names:

```
radMD.PlotArea.XAxis.DataLabelsColumn = "dtMonth";
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found out you need to set autoscale to false and then add textblock as follow:

```
                              radMD.PlotArea.XAxis.AutoScale = true;
                                for (int i = 0; i < dtMDByName.Rows.Count; i++)
                                {
                                    radMD.PlotArea.XAxis[i].TextBlock.Text = dtMDByName.Rows[i][3].ToString();
                                }
```

Comment: I have same issue and I have tried your solution first it was working fine now its giving me null reference exception i do not know why is it so? :/

Comment: Before assigning the XAxis Textblock check for null/count on Rows.

Comment: Sorry its index out of range exception :/

Comment: yes same thing check for count of Rows first, as you are taking third column if it doesnt exit you will get that exception

Comment: Values are there I can see them but still its throwing this exception.. Let me share the question with you

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22349591/how-to-set-the-x-axis-label-of-radchart-values-using-liststring Here is the question

Comment: Got the problem i forgot to add the Range. But now I am unable to set the label of Y-axis. Can you please have a look at the question? ThankYou @Zaki