# How to set the Y-Axis Label of radChart values using List<string>

Tags: c#, telerik, radchart

How can I set the X-Axis labels using radChart as I am getting the IndexOutOfRange Exception I do not what is the reason behaind this.

```
public void setchart()
{
   radChart.Clear();
   radChart.BringToFront();
   radChart.ChartTitle.TextBlock.Text = "Total Number Of Units Per Rack";
   this.Controls.Add(radChart);
   radChart.Dock =DockStyle.Fill;
   radChart.PlotArea.Appearance.Dimensions.Height = 500;
   radChart.PlotArea.XAxis.AxisLabel.Visible = true;
   radChart.PlotArea.XAxis.AxisLabel.TextBlock.Text = "UnitProcessDetailType";
   radChart.PlotArea.XAxis.AxisLabel.TextBlock.Appearance.TextProperties.Color = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
   radChart.PlotArea.XAxis.Appearance.Width = 1;
   radChart.PlotArea.XAxis.Appearance.Color = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
   radChart.PlotArea.XAxis.Appearance.LabelAppearance.RotationAngle = 45;

   radChart.PlotArea.YAxis.AxisLabel.Visible = true;
   radChart.PlotArea.YAxis.AxisLabel.TextBlock.Text = "Number Of Units";
   radChart.PlotArea.YAxis.AxisLabel.TextBlock.Appearance.TextProperties.Color = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
   radChart.PlotArea.YAxis.Appearance.Width = 1;
   radChart.PlotArea.YAxis.Appearance.Color = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
   radChart.Chart.Skin = "Sunset";

   Telerik.Charting.ChartSeries chartSeries = new Telerik.Charting.ChartSeries();
   chartSeries.Name = "Number Of Units Per Type";
   chartSeries.Type = Telerik.Charting.ChartSeriesType.Bar;
   chartSeries.Appearance.BarWidthPercent = 70;
   radChart.PlotArea.XAxis.AutoScale = false;

   ReportGrid.Controls.Add(radChart);

   List<string> xaxisLabel = new List<string>();
   List<string> yaxislabel = new List<string>();

   if (masterTab1.HeaderGrid.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString() == "Sales Quotes by Quote Status")
   {
       DataTable table = new DataTable();

       table = Adapter.SalesQuotesbyQuoteStatus(GroupList.SelectedText.ToString(), TimePeriodList.SelectedText.ToString());

         int number = table.Rows.Count;
            int column = table.Columns.Count;
            radChart.PlotArea.XAxis.AddRange(1, number, 1);
            radChart.PlotArea.YAxis.AddRange(1 , 1 , 1);
        foreach (DataRow dr in table.Rows)
        {
             xaxisLabel.Add(dr["X_Axis"].ToString());
             yaxislabel.Add(dr["Y_Axis"].ToString());
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < table.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            chartSeries.AddItem(Convert.ToDouble(yaxislabel[i]), xaxisLabel[i]);
        }

        for (int xaxis = 0; xaxis < xaxisLabel.Count; xaxis++)
        {
                radChart.PlotArea.XAxis[xaxis].TextBlock.Text = xaxisLabel[xaxis];
        }

        for (int yaxis = 0; yaxis < yaxislabel.Count; yaxis++)
        {
             radChart.PlotArea.YAxis[yaxis].TextBlock.Text = yaxislabel[yaxis];
        }

            radChart.Series.Add(chartSeries);

        }



    }
```

The List also contain values as I have checked it again and again , now I do not know what is the actual problem?

Answer (score 0):

I dont know the exact problem but the reason behind the error **IndexOutOfRangeException** may be like this as follows,

For Example:
In Main, we use a new array of length 100. This means that the array is a reference to object data of size 100 integers. You can access the array elements through array subscripts, as with array[0], array[1], through array[99].

**Tip**:The top index you can access equals the total length minus one. If you access an index past 99, you get an IndexOutOfRangeException.